# how to remove parent movieclip from child movieclip ain actionscript 3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

below shows how to add child in a movieclip.
 ebd.target.addChild(info_grd);

there is button named `my_btn` inside the movieclip `info_grd`.I would like to remove movieclip `info_grd.parent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code would be something like :

```
delete_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK , del);

function del(e:MouseEvent)
{
    this.parent.removeChildAt(0);
}
```

what I am doing here is adding a movie clip from library and adding a child to it ,  when I click on delete it will delete the parent.

```
var mm:mm1 = new mm1();
//Adding it to stage
addChild(mm);

var m2:mm2 = new mm2();
//adding the child to mm
mm.addChild(m2);
```

Comment: `this.parent.removeChildAt(0);` in the braces we input the movieclip level right?

Comment: you can see good examples here as well : http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#removeChildAt()

Answer (score 1):

Amir's code assumes there's only one child, and thus won't work when you add more children.

This code will perform the correct behavior:

```
deleteButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK , removeFromParent);

function removeFromParent(event:MouseEvent)
{
    var child:DisplayObject = event.currentTarget as DisplayObject;
    var parent:DisplayObjectContainer = child.parent;

    parent.removeChild(child);
}
```

Comment: it will not works..i had tried this `event.target.parent.parent.removeChild(event.target.parent.parent);`.Or is there any convenient methods

Comment: Don't use `event.target` when dealing with mouse events, most of the time it's NOT what you expect. Also, you are trying to remove an item from itself, which is illogical.

Comment: I believe your code assumes the deleteButton is the MovieClip @Akhil is trying to remove. But I believe they are trying to remove the parent of info_grd.

Comment: @Akhil You should put a few checks to see if the parents do actually exist, but trying something like this event.currentTarget .parent.parent.removeChild(event.currentTarget .parent);